# implement a general method later in c++

Tags: c++

I know the following code won't compile, but I posted it anyway because it exemplifies what I am trying to accomplish.

```
typedef struct {
    void actionMethod();
}Object;

Object myObject;

void myObject.actionMethod() {
    // do something;
}

Object anotherObject;

void anotherObject.actionMethod() {
    // do something else;
}

main() {
    myObject.actionMethod();
    anotherObject.actionMethod();
}
```

Basically what I want is some kind of delegate. Is there some easy way to do this?

I can't include the `<functional>` header and use `std::function` either. How can I do this?

Comment: You could have the object store a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct AnObject {
    void (*actionMethod)();
};

void anActionMethod() {
    cout << "This is one implementation" << endl;
}

void anotherActionMethod() {
    cout << "This is another implementation" << endl;
}

int main() {
    AnObject myObject, anotherObject;
    myObject.actionMethod = &anActionMethod;
    anotherObject.actionMethod = &anotherActionMethod;

    myObject.actionMethod();
    anotherObject.actionMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is one implementation 
This is another implementation
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `Object` a function pointer member:

```
struct Object {
    void (*actionMethod)();
};
```

Here, the member `actionMethod` is a pointer to function taking no arguments and returning nothing. Then, let's say you have a function called `foo`, you can set `actionMethod` to point at that function like so:

```
Object myObject;
myObject.actionMethod = &foo;
```

Which you can then call with `myObject.actionmethod()`.